# Optimize join with regex

Tags: regex, optimization, join, hive

I have one table (A) with a phrase, and the other (B) is a phrase that I want to find WITHIN table A's phrase. So I'm joining them as follows:

```sql
Create table C as
SELECT A.*
FROM A
JOIN B
where (A.phrase LIKE concat("%",B.phrase,"%"));
```

It is taking a long time because it's only using one reducer, and I believe this has to do with the nature of the query? Is there a way of speeding this up? I don't think a mapjoin or bucketjoin would help, because I'm not equating two columns, but rather, searching within one table for words from another table...

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was that Hive doesn't do non equi joins well. So I did equi joins to get a subset of table A before I did the non equi join regex. So, 3 steps. 1) Break A.phrase and B.phrase into individual words. 2) Equate these words to see which keywords from B.phrase are equal to any keywords from A.phrase - this gives a subset of table A where A.phrase contains at least one keyword from B.phrase. 3) Use this table A subset to find the whole "%B.phrase%".

Comment: Thanks for the update! Please post that as an answer to make it easier for other users to find your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was that Hive doesn't do **non equi joins** well. So I did **equi joins** to get a subset of table A before I did the non equi join regex. So, 3 steps.

1. Break A.phrase and B.phrase into individual words.
2. Equate these words to see which keywords from B.phrase are equal to any keywords from A.phrase - this gives a subset of table A where A.phrase contains at least one keyword from B.phrase.
3. Use this table A subset to find the whole "%B.phrase%".

Answer (score 1):

I think that `EXISTS` may be faster simply because your query will return same row from `A` multiple times for every match:

```
SELECT 
   A.* 
FROM A as a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 
    1 
  FROM B 
  WHERE a.phrase LIKE concat("%",phrase,"%")
);
```